# Position SVG Rectangle absolutely outside of viewbox using python

Tags: python, svg, viewbox

I am generating an SVG image in python. This part of the code works fine and uses a viewbox to position the main image in the right place.

My problem comes because I want to add a background colour. I am adding a rectangle after the main image creation and I want to position it to cover the whole image (I dont care about overflow). The obvious thing to do would be to position it at the origin but I can't work out why the x axis is at zero and the y axis is off by quite a long way. How can I position the rectangle at the origin regardless of what the viewbox might specify?

This code gives the image below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="2600px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 576 432" width="1600px">
 <rect fill="#FF5B00" height="1184" stroke="#000000" width="768" x="0" y="0"/>
```

white box is the canvas, orange box is the background rectangle I am trying to add. I have removed the main image from this example as its not relevant to this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Its simply because the aspect ratio has changed and so the viewbox cant fill the full y axis. The following code fixed it

```
preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin meet"
```